# How to include erlang cassandra client files into ejabberd server?

Tags: erlang, cassandra, cql3

I need to use erlang cassandra client(https://github.com/iamaleksey/seestar) in my ejabberd server for message logging purpose.But I can run seestar client separately.But if I include seestar files into ejabberd src folder, I ran into function_clause error.This error tells no gen_server's call function found.Please suggest some solution?

```
 The error when I debug the code is :
(ejabberd@localhost)1> seestar_session_tests:session_test_().
{foreach,#Fun<seestar_session_tests.0.112079720>,
         #Fun<seestar_session_tests.1.112079720>,
         [#Fun<seestar_session_tests.2.112079720>,
          #Fun<seestar_session_tests.3.112079720>,
          #Fun<seestar_session_tests.4.112079720>,
          #Fun<seestar_session_tests.5.112079720>]}
(ejabberd@localhost)2> seestar_session_tests:test_schema_queries(0.112079720).

** exception exit: {{function_clause,[{gen,call,
                                           [0.11207972,'$gen_call',
                                            {request,7,
                                                     <<0,0,0,95,67,82,69,65,84,69,32,75,69,89,83,80,...>>,
                                                     true},
                                            infinity],
                                           [{file,"gen.erl"},{line,146}]},
                                      {gen_server,call,3,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,184}]},
                                      {seestar_session,request,3,
                                                       [{file,"seestar_session.erl"},{line,209}]},
                                      {seestar_session,perform,3,
                                                       [{file,"seestar_session.erl"},{line,156}]},
                                      {seestar_session_tests,test_schema_queries,1,
                                                             [{file,"seestar_session_tests.erl"},{line,33}]},
                                      {erl_eval,do_apply,6,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,576}]},
                                      {shell,exprs,7,[{file,"shell.erl"},{line,668}]},
                                      {shell,eval_exprs,7,[{file,"shell.erl"},{line,623}]}]},
                    {gen_server,call,
                                [0.11207972,
                                 {request,7,
                                          <<0,0,0,95,67,82,69,65,84,69,32,75,69,89,83,80,65,67,69,
                                            ...>>,
                                          true},
                                 infinity]}}
     in function  gen_server:call/3 (gen_server.erl, line 188)
     in call from seestar_session:request/3 (seestar_session.erl, line 209)
     in call from seestar_session:perform/3 (seestar_session.erl, line 156)
     in call from seestar_session_tests:test_schema_queries/1 (seestar_session_tests.erl, line 33)
```

Comment: Could you show the exact error message you get?  You can edit the question and add it there.

Comment: I have updated my question legoscia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not supposed to call the functions in `seestar_session_tests` directly, but through the Eunit library.  Try this instead:

```
eunit:test(seestar_session_tests, [verbose]).
```

(The exact cause of the error above is that `seestar_session_tests:test_schema_queries` expects a pid, which the test framework would give it, but you invoke it with a floating point number.)

The Eunit tests can also be invoked from the commond line through Rebar.  Change to the `seestar` directory and run `rebar eunit`.

Comment: Hi, legoscia , Thanks for quick reply and Your solution worked well.Once again thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [erlcass](https://github.com/silviucpp/erlcass) which is based on [Datastax Official Cpp driver](https://github.com/datastax/cpp-driver). 
To integrate just add it as dep to your rebar config file:

`{erlcass, ".*", {git, "https://github.com/silviucpp/erlcass.git", {tag, "v2.2"}}}`

Then into your application start method initialize the driver or use into you app.config the following:

```
{
    erlcass,
    [
        {
            cluster_options,
            [
                {contact_points, <<"127.0.0.1">>},
                {port, 9042},
                {number_threads_io, 4},
                {queue_size_io, 128000},
                {max_connections_host, 5},
                {pending_requests_high_watermark, 128000},
                {tcp_nodelay, true},
                {tcp_keepalive, {true, 1800}},
                {keyspace, <<"keyspace_kere">>}
            ]
        }
    ]
}.
```